# What to do when finite counterterms are undetermined?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, s-matrix-theory

Suppose I have some theory of "new physics" which involves interaction of some gauge boson with Standard model. For this theory I have some loop-mediated process with this new gauge boson whose matrix element contains logarithmic divergence. I can introduce new vertex which calcels this divergence. Unfortunately, I don't have experimental values of parameters of this theory, so the finite counterterms are not determined. But I want to make theoretical predictions about the probability of this process.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

The problem is particularly described in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903044v1) paper.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Is it i) you have a new theory with an unspecified and unmeasured parameter. How do you make predictions? or ii) your theory doesn't make definite predictions because calculations involve arbitrary constants of e.g. integration? what do you do?

Comment: @innisfree : it seems that I was inattentive, because the answer contains in linked paper. Also, people've stucked with the same problem in case of triangle-mediated decay $h \to 2 \gamma$.